# How to simulate a "open link on new window" on Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I wanted to simulate a mouse click to open link on new Safari window (not new tab). I've been trying with **InitMouseEvent**, but it doesn't work as expected.

As you can see from Safari Preference dialog, the key combinations are Shift + Alt/Opt + Command + mouse click.

[Safari Preference Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuxyT.png)

With the provided key combinations, I just need to set metaKey, shiftKey, and altKey to be true as InitMouseEvent's parameters.

```
<body>
    <button onClick="test()">test</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = "https://test.test";

            const evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            const ctrlKey = false;
            const altKey = true;
            const shiftKey = true;
            const metaKey = true;
            const button = 0;
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, null);

            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

However, Safari just ignored these parameters and allowed only left-click action. No matter how you change any parameters to any value, it will produce the same action which is left-click resulting the whole page navigated to new site.

I also compared the events between programmatic and user click and found out an event's property **isTrusted** was false when programmatically clicked. Not sure if Safari used this property to ignore my **initMouseEvent**.

I couldn't figure out other solutions and would like to ask for suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your suggestion. I also tried window.open, but I got new popup instead of new window.